# Objective C - Vector of Objects not holding value between methods

Tags: objective-c, object, vector

I am new to Objective-C, but I have a background in C++. I am working on the front end of a project and I am using apple's interface builder and xcode.

I have a vector that holds objects of a class, `vector<myClass> myVector`, in another class `bigClass`. myClass holds 15 `NSMutableString*` variables. I have another vector that is local the method I declare it in `vector<myClass> vector2` that performs SQL queries to fetch the data I want. I then assign the values from `vector2` to `myVector`.

I set each variable of like this:`[myVector[i].a  setString: vector2[i].a];` and `myVector` is declared in my head like this: `@property vector<myClass> myVector`

I am able to read the values that I put in `myVector` in the method, however when a different method of `bigClass` gets class I am only to get the first 3 variable's value and the fifth variable's value for each object of the class that is in `myVector` every other attempt to get the value of a variable that is not one of those four results in a seg fault. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> I set each variable of like this:`[myVector[i].a  setString: vector2[i].a];`

`vector` is a C++ container and doesn't know anything about Objective-C memory management. Objective-C uses a reference counted memory model which you can read about in [About Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html). Since `vector` doesn't follow the memory management rules, the objects you store in a `vector` will be deallocated as soon as no other objects are retaining them, i.e. at the end of the method in which you deallocate them.

Rather than trying to use `vector` to store your objects, use `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`, both of which work perfectly with Objective-C objects.